# Error ao usar múltiplos BDs em Django

Tags: django

Olá

Estou estudando como adicionar dois bancos de dados no django e estou encontrando um problema.

Quando eu utilizo o **using** no método listar, ele consegue usar o banco de dados escolhido e lista os clientes no template.

```py
def listar_clientes():
    clientes = Cliente.objects.using('leitura').all()
    return clientes
```

Porém ao utlizar o router encontro seguinte problema:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. 
"
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings doc
umentation for more details.
```

Código do Router:

```py
class Router(object):
    def db_for_read(self, models, **hints):
        return 'leitura'

    def db_for_write(self, models, **hints):
        return 'escrita'
```

settings.py:

```py
....


DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'escrita': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'tw_django_orm_escrita',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306'
    },
    'leitura': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'tw_django_orm_leitura',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306'
    },
}

DATABASES_ROUTERS = ['clientes.router.Router']

....
```

Preciso de uma ajuda para solucionar esse problema!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa remover o `'default': {},`. Ele está tentando achar a configuração de `"ENGINE"` nesse dicionário e não consegue.

Eu sugiro você deixar o default como o seu banco de escrita e criar um com o nome de replica onde a replica é o de leitura.

Eu gosto de trabalhar com a seguinte configuração para produção:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": os.getenv("DB_ENGINE", "django.db.backends.sqlite3"),
        "NAME": os.getenv("DB_DATABASE", os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3")),
        "USER": os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("DB_HOST"),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("DB_PORT"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD"),
    }
}

DATABASES["default"]["CONN_MAX_AGE"] = int(os.getenv("DB_CONN_MAX_AGE", 0))  # type: ignore

if os.getenv("USE_REPLICA"):
    DATABASES["replica"] = {
        "ENGINE": os.getenv("DB_ENGINE_REPLICA"),
        "NAME": os.getenv("DB_DATABASE_REPLICA"),
        "USER": os.getenv("DB_USER_REPLICA"),
        "HOST": os.getenv("DB_HOST_REPLICA"),
        "PORT": os.getenv("DB_PORT_REPLICA"),
        "PASSWORD": os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD_REPLICA"),
    }
    DATABASES["replica"]["CONN_MAX_AGE"] = int(os.getenv("DB_CONN_MAX_AGE_REPLICA", 0))  # type: ignore
    DATABASE_ROUTERS = ["MY_PROJECT.support.db_routing.DatabaseRouter"]
```

Meu router é:

```
class DatabaseRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth application.
    """

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Always read from REPLICA database
        """
        return "replica"

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Always write to DEFAULT database
        """
        return "default"

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Objects from REPLICA and DEFAULT are de same, then True always
        """
        return True

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Only DEFAULT database
        """
        return db == "default"
```

Se vc quiser manter a sua configuração sem o `default`, vc deve configurar todos os métodos da classe `DatabaseRouter` que retornam default por padrão. Como o `def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):`

A documentação oficial para consulta é: [Multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/)

Comment: Perfeito!! Funcionou usando o banco de escrita como default. Muito Obrigado!!!

Comment: +1 A resposta foi boa, mas seria legal você adicionar links para a documentação dos conceitos que você está utilizando. Assim algum outro usuário com problemas parecidos terá melhor embasamento para modificar e adaptar sua solução para o problema dele.